# How do I create post template for different taxonomy

Tags: templates, taxonomy

I have created taxonomy, but I want to use different post template for the taxonomy, how can I do it?

```
function create_topics_hierarchical_taxonomy() {

// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
//first do the translations part for GUI

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'cars', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'cars', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Topics' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Topics' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Topic' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Topic:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Topic' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Topic' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Topic' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Topic Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'cars' ),
  );    

// Now register the taxonomy

  register_taxonomy('cars',array('post'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cars' ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create taxonomy template like `taxonomy-[Your-texonomy].php` in your theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create via archive-cars.php - That will display all cars info 
and if you want single template then you have to use your post type in file .

single-{post_type}.php

for more information you can review WP template Hierarchy
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/